# Executable Statemachine code generatation

Tags: simulation, state-machine, enterprise-architect

I use EA 12 to simulate a model.
I've created a class with a statemachine, then added a new diagram with an "executable-statemachine" artifact and dragged the class into it as a property.

I would like now to generate the statemachine code.
When I right-click on the artifact, the "code engineering" menu is missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: It might be a license issue. Check the comparison list on Sparx site.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, Thanks- That's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu is missing due to the Corporate Edition I used.
Changing the license to Ultimate Edition makes it work!